# Are there any performance difference between these 2 queries?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017, sqlperformance

Query 1 - UserId is the main identifier, non-clustered index

```
update myTable set 
CurrentHp=MaximumHp,
SelectedAttack1RemainingPP=SelectedAttack1MaximumPP,
SelectedAttack2RemainingPP=SelectedAttack2MaximumPP,
SelectedAttack3RemainingPP=SelectedAttack3MaximumPP,
SelectedAttack4RemainingPP=SelectedAttack4MaximumPP where UserId=1001695
```

Query 2

```
    update myTable set 
    CurrentHp=MaximumHp,
    SelectedAttack1RemainingPP=SelectedAttack1MaximumPP,
    SelectedAttack2RemainingPP=SelectedAttack2MaximumPP,
    SelectedAttack3RemainingPP=SelectedAttack3MaximumPP,
    SelectedAttack4RemainingPP=SelectedAttack4MaximumPP 
    where UserId=1001695 
    and
    (
    SelectedAttack1RemainingPP!=SelectedAttack1MaximumPP 
or 
SelectedAttack2RemainingPP!=SelectedAttack2MaximumPP 
or 
SelectedAttack3RemainingPP!=SelectedAttack3MaximumPP 
or
SelectedAttack4RemainingPP!=SelectedAttack4MaximumPP
or 
CurrentHp!=MaximumHp
    )
```

When i check via SQL server management studio and compare "Include Actual Execution Plan", their cost is same

However when i check via Include Client Statistics, I see that the first query shows 1900 rows updated while the second one shows 0 rows updated

So here my question, when column A and B value are equal, do SQL still make an update?

I also logically think that both query should be same but i would like to hear your opinion

execution plan same performance image

[image]

client statistics query 1

[image]

client statistics query 2

[image]

Comment: if one query updates rows but another doesn't, then it is not a performance difference, it's a difference in effect of the queries.

Comment: SQL Server does not and cannot skip "null updates" -- the operation is still logically an observable update that might interact with other transactions and must, for consistency, be written into the transaction log. So no, these queries are not the same (and explicitly skipping updates when you know they'll do nothing can be a valuable technique).

Comment: @JeroenMostert good definition null update. so can we say that query 2 is better with explicit definition?

Comment: @Cato both actually doesnt make any changes to the rows. because the row values are already same. but what Jeroen Mostert said makes sense

Comment: You could include `SelectedAttack1RemainingPP is null or SelectedAttack2RemainingPP is null or SelectedAttack3RemainingPP is null or SelectedAttack4RemainingPP is null or CurrentHp is null or` in the mix. Because `NULL!=1` evaluates as NULL Never think of NULL as "Empty", but think of it as "Unknown".

Answer (score 0):

Two execution plans are the same because your first filter condition (UserId=1001695) chooses just one row and the table has an index on this field.
If you change your queries as a range condition  such as (userID > 100), the costs in execution plans changed and they are not the same, or if your filter is in another field that table does not have index on it, the structures of execution plans are changed and they are not the same.